# C# Как удалить файл во время его использования?

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте, уважаемые участники форума! Наткнулся на очередной подводный камень и очень надеюсь на Вашу поддержку. Имеется приложение, которое все время должно быть запущено. С другого компьютера по локальной сети высылаются файлы, которые должны заменить файлы этого приложения, в частности логотип в программе. Я использую контейнер pictureBox:

```
    pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"Images\\Logo.jpg");
```

Когда приходят новые файлы я пытаюсь заменить эту картинку на новую:

```
            try
                {
                    pictureBox2.Image = null;
                    File.Delete("Images\\Logo.jpg");
                }
                catch (Exception ea) {
                  MessageBox.Show("Пацан, процесс используется! Ты шо ебобо?");
                }
```

Но выкидывает исключение: "Необработанное исключение типа "System.IO.IOException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "D:bin\Debug\Images\Logo.jpg", так как этот файл используется другим процессом.

Как можно решить эту проблему? 
P.s. Также я пытался подставить временно другую картинку вместо старой, но все равно файл занят

```
       pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"Reserv.jpg");
       File.Delete("Images\\Logo.jpg");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Извини, я чуть ошибся.
Вот работает:`FileStream fs = FileStream("путь",FileMode.Open);
PictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(fs);
fs.Close()`

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! А не подскажите еще как sr загрузить в pictureBox, какой синтаксис?

Comment: pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(sr); Не компилируется такое вот)

Comment: @AlexFox попробуй, исправленый, выше

Comment: Да, помогло! Огромное СПАСИБО!